# Monotonicity of projected gradient descent on a closed convex set

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, numerical-optimization

Let $C\subset R^n$ be a closed convex set, $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ differentible.

The update step of the projected gradient descent algorithm is
$$x^{t+1}=P_C(x^t-\alpha\nabla f(x^t))$$
where $P_C(\cdot)$ is the projection operator on $C$.

I am trying to prove **the monotonicity property**, i.e. that for $\alpha$ small enough it holds that
$$f(x^{t+1})\leq f(x^t)$$

**What i have so far**.

The  projection operator has the properties that
$$(x-P_C(x))^T(z-P_C(x))\leq 0,\ \forall z\in C$$
$$||P_C(x)-P_C(y)||\leq||x-y||$$
So
$$(x^t-\alpha\nabla f(x^t)-x^{t+1})^T(x^t-x^{t+1})\leq 0\ \to$$
$$||x^t-x^{t+1}||^2-\alpha\nabla f(x^t)^T(x^t-x^{t+1})\leq 0\ \to$$
$$\nabla f(x^t)^T(x^t-x^{t+1})\geq\frac{1}{\alpha}||x^t-x^{t+1}||^2$$
By differentiability of $f$.
$$f(x^{t+1})-f(x^t)=\nabla f(x^t)^T(x^{t+1}-x^t)+o(||x^{t+1}-x^t||)$$
Also $o(||x^{t+1}-x^t||)=o(\alpha)$ because
$$||x^{t+1}-x^t||=||P_C(x^t-\alpha\nabla f(x^t))-P_C(x^t)||\leq\alpha||\nabla f(x^t)||$$
So from these
$$f(x^{t+1})-f(x^t)\leq-\frac{1}{\alpha}||x^t-x^{t+1}||^2+o(\alpha)=-\alpha(\frac{1}{\alpha^2}||x^t-x^{t+1}||^2-\frac{o(\alpha)}{\alpha})$$
So i need to show that $\frac{1}{\alpha^2}||x^t-x^{t+1}||^2-\frac{o(\alpha)}{\alpha}\geq 0$ for $\alpha$ small enough.

If i have a positive lower bound $c$ independent of $\alpha$
$$\frac{1}{\alpha^2}||x^t-x^{t+1}||^2\geq c$$
or if i can show that
$$\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac{1}{\alpha^2}||x^t-x^{t+1}||^2=c>0$$
Then the proof will be complete. But i don't see how to get to one of these results. Or maybe you have another way to prove (or disprove) monotonicity of the algorithm.

Comment: I may help you : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856559/why-does-the-projected-gradient-descent-method-work?rq=1

Comment: @jvc Thanks, but i don't see how this can help.

Comment: @Koncopd can you indicate why not? Is it because the answer to that question contains 'just heuristic arguments'?

Comment: My question is about  proving the specific property of the projected gradient descent method, not "why it works". Also in the outline of my partial proof i already have $\nabla f(x^t)^T(x^t-x^{t+1})\geq\frac{1}{\alpha}||x^t-x^{t+1}||^2$, which implies the result $\nabla f(x^t)^T(x^{t+1}-x^t)<0$ in the link. So i don't see how it adds anything.

Comment: In general, you need an upper bound on $||\nabla f||$ or this argument cannot work. Also the function $f$ needs to be convex for the algorithm to converge. For a proof of the convergence refer to [page 6 here](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos521/lecnotes/lec19.pdf). This should be modifiable to prove monotonicity as well.

Comment: It is clear how to get this result for a convex function or a function with Lipschitz continuous gradient, but i am interested in the case described in the question. Also, i am interested only in monotonicity, not in convergence. Monotonicity holds for the ordinary gradient descent, so my thought is that it should hold also for the projected variant.